# A society in which the "family system" is similar to those of lions or monkeys

Tags: evolution, family

I envisioned a world where people are not bounded by marriage and females are free to choose those who they deem "accomplished" and have offspring with him.

The males "occasionally" interact with the young and "educate" them to be better than the others, therefore making sure their genes are passed onward, much like lions or monkeys in our world act.

The only problem is my race is "highly intelligent" and has a strong sense of "moral".

And here comes the REAL problem:

The "less accomplished males" will definitely grow jealous and envious!

NOBODY will accept the fate that he is inferior to others and just die, ESPECIALLY when he is "intelligent"!

And the long period of "lacking female companion" (plus jealousy and envy) will definitely twist your mind and get you to commit unspeakable crimes such as rape or murder.

And that is "most of the society"!

So if this kind of system was practiced for too long, bad things are bound to happen!

So are there ways to prevent this sort of thing from happening!? In other words how does this society "keep everybody happy"!?

Comment: "Moral" simply means that you follow the mores of **your own society**. While some religions have reasonable claim to universal systems of ethics, morals are unfortunately always relative to the social context. So "strongly moral" simply means that they strongly support the system you described and feel it is the correct and proper one. Being intelligent is irrelevant to this.

Comment: @VilleNiemi Please see my update. Thanks!

Comment: welcome to worldbuilding. I struggle to understand your problem. Striving to improve one's condition is the cornerstone of the capitalist way of living, and morality is purely a convention among individuals. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to better understand our community.

Comment: @L.Dutch Thanks for your comment. "Striving to improve one's condition" could NEVER beat the "gene"! One could NEVER be Einstein or Stephen Hawking no matter how hard he/she studied! Unless you're born with the advantage. That's why I say the way I say it. Should I put these in my question!?

Comment: *"My race is [...] have a strong sense of morals":* Morals vary immensely from time to time and from place to place. The Mongols had a very strong moral sense. The Arabs had a very strong moral sense. The Vandals had a very strong moral sense. The Persians had a very strong moral sense. The Greeks and the Romans had a very strong moral sense. But some of them plundered half the world, some of them practiced polygamy, some of them acquired a reputation as the ultimate shifty merchants and so on; and *none* of those examples had the morals of modern western Europeans...

Comment: *"And the long period of "lacking female companion" (plus jealousy and envy) will definitely twist your mind and commit unspeakable crimes such as rape or murder."* [``[Citation Needed]``](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation_needed)

Comment: Related answer: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/56014/23519

Comment: @Chronocidal While that exact _causation_ has not been proved (AFAIK), plenty of studies shows the link. [University of BC 2012](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2012/01/120124093142.htm), [Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rstb.2011.0290), [The Economist 2017](https://www.economist.com/christmas-specials/2017/12/19/the-link-between-polygamy-and-war)

Comment: The real problem is your lack of a developed legal and governing system that has developed to protect the transfer of wealth through the mating process.  The majority of law could be said to have developed from the simple claim, "that's mine."  Hereditary titles, dowries, even the clothes on one's back, all become owned/shared leading to the definition of what it means for something to be "mine," which is one of the bases of marriage.  Your society may have started with something reflecting lions and monkeys, but add intelligence and marriage would quickly follow.

Comment: I really take some issue with the idea that any male not provided with a 'mating partner' with surely snap and become a rapist/murderer.  Do you really have such a low view of men?

Comment: @Meg Absolutely.  If only we had centuries of [real-world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monk) [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhikkhu) of males without "mating partners" who managed to live a "good" life for testing this hypothesis...  Oh, wait.

Comment: There are specie son Earth which follow a somewhat similar system and might possibly have human intelligence levels and be people.  They include elephants and Sperm whales, for example.  Thus it is possible that there actually are such societies on Earth.

Comment: @Meg and Choronocidal, I apologize for such a STRONG statement! I should've clarify that I didn't mean "all of them"!

Comment: @M.A.Golding I doubt that in current "moral standard" of Earth ("Some" country even rub their noses in somebody else's business), such a society could ever exist! Otherwise I would be "VERY" interested in research them!

Comment: I "suspect" that the "OP" does not "understand" the correct "usage" of quotation marks.

Comment: @PcMan That's very well be the case because English is not my native language. I just want to put some emphasize on some points more than the others. I sincerely apologize for the incorrect usage of the symbol!

Comment: NOBODY *wants* to accept the *fact* that he is inferior. 'just dying' is exactly what usually happens to the outliers *of all mammalian species* : "The social group basically polices itself and enforces the rules of social dominance, the social mores of the troupe, and monkeys who don't pay attention to those rules -who are overly aggressive in their interactions- don't last in that troupe very long. **They're kicked out of the troupe. They go solitary and most of them don't survive.**" – Steven Suomi, *Origins of [Human Aggression](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/a/22651/9910)*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basically, lions and monkeys survive because the males are to "prove themselves" by surviving the wild on their own, whereas females are sheltered by the group which makes survival for them much easier and tips the scales in favour of females meaning that there are more adult females and they work together as a group.

When you have a more "intelligent" society by which I suppose you mean also a technologically more advanced society, you will have to change the way in which the males have to prove themselves to the females. 
Two possible options of roles for your males are reasonable:

1. "the protector of society". Basically, being a good, reliable and trustworthy bodyguard, soldier, police man etc. earns you the right to be chosen by the females. This will not happen in your first years, but as an accomplished officer of 30+ years you will become eligible by females pretty much like in a dating service. In this way the physical fitness of offspring is guaranteed and these males are also all part of a strict moral code of "keeping to the laws" and always keep in training to still be able to perform in their jobs. In addition, they have a strong personal interest to do their jobs well, as they protect their own and the other children and women in the society.
2. "the scholar". Those are the intellectual upkeepers of society, scholars, scientists, engineers who will also have to invest years into their education and intellectual training. Again they will have to raise through the ranks of the "scientific community", making only the ones who have finished their PhD, published a certain amount of papers or research to find a certain number of patents eligible for producing offspring. Here, the genes of the most highly intelligent are to be passed on for the better of the society. While not the ones to protect their own and others offspring and no ideal for physical fitness, they will be the ones to educate their own and others' elected children and guide them to intellectual understanding under their tutelage.

In this way, the females can choose between an intellectual or a muscle man as their respective partners to foster the physical and intellectual fitness of their whole community.

Comment: Then how about "keep everybody happy"!? Can you add some resolution to the "Lesser-Accomplished" problem please!? Thanks!

Comment: @PiggyChu001 no society can ever keep literally everyone happy. But in this way, every person has the chance to gain the privileged position instead of casting the majority of the male population out a priori.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept your answer as the best answer!

Comment: You could expand the possible options, since a technological society need a lot more than just scientist, engineers and policemen. The main point is, if in [competence field] you prove yourself to be reliable, competent and intelligent, you will gain the "dating rights", with every competence fields having their own sets of acomplishments.

Comment: @DrakaSAN You are of course right. This is definitely very boiled down. But it shows two large and very different paths with of course a lot in between and additional ways of expanding the social system depending on the actual parameters on the society's size, state of development etc.

Comment: They might not have pleasure in have sex, and would think about it only for procreation, assume the fittest should be the one that would procreate and even be honored if someone fit where to have sex with someone they knew  or something like that.

Answer (score 8):

When a female gives birth, most of the newbornes are females. The general makeup of your society could be 10-20% male and the rest female. This would encourage more females to get together with less accomplished, because the top 5% are already with a certain amount of females.
To pronounce this, you could etablish a social maximum of wives/partners a male can have, either due to social or biological reasons.

Comment: this won't work I think without something forcing a non-even birthrate as it would genetically advantage females that gave birth to males

Comment: @jk. could you please elaborate? I had asumed some litter-style reproduction, and that out of every litter there are only a few males. If this species does single-child-pregnancies by default, it would not work (or not as good).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_principle

Comment: I agree with jk because this won't work without tempering with the reproduction procedure, and it defeat the purpose of "females choosing whom they deemed accomplished". Maybe a society where females are all go to the sperm bank and choose whose sperm to fertilize her egg!? But what's the fun in that!?

Comment: Evolution tends to result in an equal number of males and females, even if only a small fraction of the males end up fathering all the children. Just consider all the living species on Earth.

Comment: Fisher's principle is actually that mothers will spend and equal amount of resources on male and female children so if one sex were to be born earlier and less developed then equal resources would lead to a screwed sex ratio

e.g. males born in litters of 5 significantly premature compared to females born singly at full term then you'd expect more females then males overall. In other words in this case even though evolutionary males are 'better' because there are less of them, they have an investment cost which is higher which evens it out.

Comment: They could be genetically different from us in like instead of having XX or XY it could be a triple chromossome like XXX and XYY and any combination besides XYY would result into a male, it would make females alot more rare and probably make it into a very competitive society.

Answer (score 4):

You don't explicitly say, but I'm going to assume that you want a human society.  Some of this becomes easier in an alien society, as we don't have to work around actual human behavior.

> NOBODY will accept the fate that he is inferior than the others and just die, ESPECIALLY when he is "intelligent"!

Sure, so the society won't operate that way.

Instead, there will be a constant proffer of hope that some day, the currently inferior will prove himself and gain a mate.  By the time that he realizes that he never will prove himself, he is over the hill.

The initial claim will be that they are too young.  And some will graduate from that to become head of a pride.  But others will be just a bit weaker or slower.  They will always be behind the best of their age.  Some might be enough smarter or have the ability to learn to be better such that they can compete later in life.

Such a society might have a competition culture, where most lose but all think that they can win.  Perhaps the competition is kept always close.  So even the weakest and dumbest think that they are just a step away.  Individuals may spend large parts of the year training for the competitions.

The females in a pride may support one candidate over the others and give preferential treatment, adding a political component to the contests.

> And the long period of "lacking female companion" (plus jealousy and envy) will definitely twist your mind and commit unspeakable crimes such as rape or murder.

Well, the lion solution is that if you murder one of the lucky few, you become one of the lucky few.  I.e. a male leader of a pride may lose a challenge to a nomadic male, who then becomes the leader of the pride.  That might last a long time in a society like this.

Rape is more complicated.  Lions have an estrous period where they strongly want to mate and do not have sex outside it.  It is unclear if they would ever consider themselves to have been raped.  I.e. rape may not be a meaningful term to an estrous species.  Sex is more like scratching an itch than an activity pleasurable in its own right.  Humans of course work differently.

Note that male lions are greatly outnumbered by female lions in a pride.  With humans, the females might gang up together and kill an abusive male.  It's unclear what would be considered normal in such a society and what would be considered over the line.  But a male attacking a lone female would be rare, as females travel in prides.  It's only the males that travel alone or in small groups.

It is also possible that this society would have more bisexual members.  Young males might band together for companionship and sex.  Later, they might "graduate" from that to a pride.  Some may prefer the companionship of other men throughout.  This may be described as a spectrum of sexuality, ranging from only mates with females to only mates with males.  Same sex sexual activity has precedent both in humans and in lions.

An individual male who is sexually aggressive, only interested in females, and unable to find a pride might be subject to destruction or imprisonment.  Or simply may be barred from the competitive events that allow one to find a pride after breaking the rules in some way.

Males may also sublimate their sexual desire in other activities.  Or masturbate.

One reason that people would join the Catholic church was so as to remove the threat to their relatives.  Because priests and monks do not marry, they can't have (legitimate) kids.  So they are not a threat to their siblings' dynastic hopes.  This made the church a useful place to send younger noble children.  They would find alternative ways to compete, possibly advising their brothers or nephews.  Or they might compete in knowledge.  When those with knowledge but not muscle would be allowed to reproduce would be a major step toward civilization in that society.

The first step might be a particularly strong male giving his castoffs to his brother.  If someone tried to challenge the weaker brother, perhaps the stronger would fight his challenge for him.

Another option is castration.  Perhaps anyone can challenge, but if the challenge fails, the challenger is castrated.  This could be brought forward around the same time that the knowledgeable started being allowed prides.  Prior to that, the loser might always be killed.  In that circumstance, castration might be the more merciful alternative.  But as civilization develops, it will become the primitive remnant, as some see capital punishment and imprisonment now.

Both death and castration make challenges risky.  So rather than challenging constantly in the hope that you might get lucky, you prepare for one single challenge.  But the hope remains.

This allows for competitions based in something other than physical combat that still have serious consequences.  Yet another alternative would be to simply give each and every male one chance at a challenge.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer! I'll add it to my knowledge bank and see what I can do with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very interesting question, I don't know if you are speaking about sapient lions, lion-like humans or an alien species which in the past had lion behaviors, whatever my answer could work for all of this situations.

So, how all the individuals could be happy?, the answer is homosexuality and bisexuality, but before explained, first all the other features.

I'm explain a society with lion-like origins which now is in an advanced age, will be extremely competitive and meritocratic, here there is no place for corruption or dictators, the society composed principally by the females is extremely demanding with their leaders, also with their amazing and almost "patriotic" sense of belonging with their female comrades will permit them make hits of State if they considered that the leader isn't enough strong or intelligent. In the other hand males are very competitive, they keep their social groups little, so if they have the opportunity they will try to get all the credit of winning just for himself or at least for his closest "friends" (probably no more than 3 "persons").

This make almost the males extremely competitive, they constantly are training for defeat their bosses at annual "challenges" for get the reward for the cautious and demanding females, which obviously are the sex relations, get a "harem", here enters other valorations of this society, if its diverse as us, the females could have different valorations for choosing a mate, so some females could prefer scientists, others sportsmen, others politicians and many other professions, probably the The number of females that a male manages to impress will increase with his rank within a profession, now as a simple example, if any of these people have a bachelor's degree, he will be able to call the female tendency with the same degree of studies, but if he obtains a master's degree and then a doctorate then the females with less study and the same will be at his disposal, There is no greater gratification for a male than to get or rather to be chosen by the best females with which to breed. On the other hand, the reason for females to continue improving by increasing their capabilities is not to compete with others, but rather their great sense of teamwork and belonging, which are the pillars of work in this society, practically the male arrives at the jobs as boss, the females ambition more than anything to do the best possible in their comfort zone.

As example on the previous, probably in a company the most of all the workers (by the way extremely good at their work) are females guided by a male boss with just a little quantity of male workers, and the most females would be interested in the boss, while just a few of these females are at disposal of the less range males.

Where does homosexuality and bisexuality come in?, well some investigations shows that homosexuality appear in different species as a mechanism for reduce competence between males and for help the females with other works, in this specie homosexuality is prolific with great quantities of males non interested in compete for females, instead of that they prefer be focused on get better their comfort zone just for help, they will search male mates and just if the extremely rare situation they would procreate with females just for reproduce the specie, this would make males already resigned to failure try to pose as homosexuals for not have trouble approaching females.

While females are they are very affectionate with their companions (reason of why some loser try to get closer), physically and emotionally, I don't know if call this lesbianism but if they are always in the company of a male more interested in being the best than in giving them attention (at least until they have children), they probably prefer to satisfy each other, but here everything will depend on the importance that you want to give sexuality in your society, Since in primates sexual contact is very important to establish closeness while in lions it is only a short period a year in which they feel the need to copulate. So if you define that you want sex to be pleasant for this species, you increase the benefit of the outstanding male.